# Understanding Code - lambda expressions

Tags: c#

I was looking at this code of a sieve of eratosthenes but i still couldn't get how the "i" variable gets incremented since I have a limited knowledge about lambda expressions and the documentation didn't help me much. Can anyone explain ?

```
int cur = 1, total = 1000;
var pc = Enumerable.Range(2, total).ToList();

while(cur <= Math.Sqrt(total))
{
    cur = pc.First(i => i > cur);
    pc.RemoveAll(i => i != cur && i % cur == 0);
}

Console.WriteLine(pc.Max());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not actually incremented; in both lambda expressions in this code `i` is used as a temporary placeholder for a currently processed value(s). Namely,

```
cur = pc.First(i => i > cur);
```

means "Take first *value that* is greater than `cur` from `pc` and assign it to `cur`".

```
pc.RemoveAll(i => i != cur && i % cur == 0);
```

means "Take all *values that* are not equal to `cur` and have zero reminder from division by `cur` and remove them from pc".

Comment: So correct me if I am wrong ... During the first iteration, the first value of i will be 2?

Answer (score 0):

The variable cur is updated in the while loop:

```
cur = pc.First(i => i > cur);
```

i is simply part of the predicate which returns the first occurance where i > cur.  In other words, it's a local variable in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

Its not i but cur variable which is controlling when to exit loop

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't get incremented, it's relying on on pc having members removed until the while condition is not met.

Think of it like the difference between

```
index = 1000;
while (index > 0)
{
    pc.Remove(index);
    index--;
}
```

and

```
while (pc.Count > 0)
{
   pc.Remove(0);
}
```